# Can't see marmalade repo on emacs 24 on OSX 10.6.8

Tags: emacs, clojure, marmalade, elpa

I'm trying to set up emacs 24 to use with clojure on osx.  I've installed emacs 24 from emacsformacosx.com, and I've added the following code to ~/.emacs.d/init.el:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))

;; Add in your own as you wish:
(defvar my-packages '(starter-kit starter-kit-lisp)
  "A list of packages to ensure are installed at launch.")

(dolist (p my-packages)
  (when (not (package-installed-p p))
    (package-install p)))
```

However when I do M-x package-refresh-contents, and package-install, clojure-mode and the other marmalade packages don't show up.  The starter kit must be installed since ido-mode works, so I'm not sure what's happening.  I can go to ~/.emacs.d/elpa/archive/marmalade and see that the packages are there.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

Needed to be in ~/.emacs not ~/.emacs.d/init.el

Comment: That makes little sense. If you don't have a ~/.emacs file ~/.emacs.d/init.el is used by default.